# How to select only the photo that the mouse is on

Tags: jquery

So, my problem is I have a function to get the source of an image (see "var link"). Unfortunately it doesn't get the link of the photo I want to have the link of. Instead it getts the link of another photo in the HTML with the same class even though I use "this".:

```
$(".postimagepic").hover(function () {
    var link = $(this).attr("src").split("/").pop().split(".", 1)[0];
});
```

Do I have to work with events? Please help me :'[

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(".postimagepic").hover(function () {
    var link = $(this).attr("src").split("/").pop().split(".", 1)[0];
        
    $(this).before('<div>' + link + '</div>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result"></div>
<img class="postimagepic" src="http://bootstrapbay.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/unslpash-desert-road_uvsq5s.png">
<img class="postimagepic" src="http://bootstrapbay.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/negative-space.jpg">
<img class="postimagepic" src="http://bootstrapbay.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/hay_fields_flwqqr.jpg">
```